# Pushing props into Supabase filtering - VUE3, Supabase

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, supabase

Trying to push through a prop to the .like filtering option in supabase function. Due to .like needing % in value, im not sure how to push the prop through. Please see below.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
 const { data, error } = await supabase
 .from('sneaker')
 .select()
 .eq('brand', props.model?.brand)
 .like('name', '%Yeezy%')
 filteredList1.value = data
 console.log(data)
}
```

I would like to have props.model?.name instead of '%Yeezy%'. I have tried adding in the prop like stated but does not work. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried concatenating the string?

```
.like('name', `%${props.model?.name}%`)
```